# django DateField is charfield

Tags: django

I'm using django.forms ModelForm. I have DoB which is 'datefield', however, when I display the form the DoB it is displaying like charfield. What should I do so the user be able to select date? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

model:

```
dob = models.DateField(validators=[MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(70)],blank=True, null = True, verbose_name="Day of birth")
```

HTML:

```
<form method = 'POST' >
    {{ edit_profile | crispy}}
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <button type = 'submit' name = 'submit' class = 'btn-edit'>Save</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have faced an issue like this in the past. There is a very small fix for this. In your `forms.py` make the following changes:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Model_Name

class EquipmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Name
        fields = 'dob'
        widgets = {'dob': DateInput()}
```

This should solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Django's by default `forms.DateField` only renders as an `<input>`-tag.

To get [the browser's default date-picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) you need to give it the `type="date"` attribute.

This can be done like so:

```py
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   # ... field definitions

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       self.fields['dob'].widget.attrs.update({'type': 'date'})
```

This will render as the following HTML:

```html
<input id="id_dob" name="dob" type="date"></input>
```

Of course you don't have to do this in the form's init method.
You can do it anywhere, where you have access to the form's fields.

Edit: alternatively you can use a javascript datepicker like [tempus-dominus](https://pypi.org/project/django-tempus-dominus/).

Answer (score 0):

```
class EditProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('full_name', 'dob','introduction','twitter','facebook','linked','hobbies', 'stock', 'weather',)
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfile,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dob'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={ 'type': 'date'})
```